# Pagination with datatables

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatable, pagination

I'm following this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables.

I'm trying to get my datatables to paginate at every 10 items. My code looks like this:

```
def index
  @search = Product.search do |query|
    query.fulltext params[:sSearch]
    query.with(:store_id, @store.id)
    query.paginate(:page => page, :per_page => per_page)
  end
  @products = @search.results

  @headers = @products.map(&:data).flat_map(&:keys).uniq

  @product_data = @products.map{ |product| product[ :data ].values }

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json do
      render :json=> {
        "sEcho"               => params[:sEcho].to_i,
        "iTotalRecords"       => @products.count,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords"=> @products.count,
        "aaData"              => @product_data.as_json
      }
    end
  end
end

private
  def page
    params[:iDisplayStart].to_i/per_page + 1
  end

  def per_page
    params[:iDisplayLength].to_i > 0 ? params[:iDisplayLength].to_i : 10
  end
```

I have the will_paginate gem installed, but the datatable doesn't seem to recognize that it should be paginating, it shows up to 10 records and has the pagination buttons disabled.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'm no rails developer, but it seems to me that the problem is:

```
"iTotalRecords"       => @products.count,
```

`@products.count` it's the record count when the query is already paginated (always 10 or less depending on the page).

Try setting this value to the total number of records of the query **whitout any pagination**.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is you should be using `total_entries` instead of `count`.

So change this:

```
"iTotalDisplayRecords"=> @products.count
```

to this:

```
"iTotalDisplayRecords"=> @products.total_entries
```

Answer (score -1):

**Buttons**

You'll need to include `<%= will_paginate @products %>` in your view (this allows you to refresh the datatable with new paginated content each time:

```
#app/views/products/datatable.html.erb
<<datatable>>
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

---

**Records**

If you're seeing 10 results is because of `will_paginate`, it means you're on the right track. The gem works by using `limit` and `offset` to create a "scope" of the SQL query

Essentially, if you've implemented the gem correctly, it will only pull back the required data from the database for your view, hence the 10 results

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this just gets will_paginate's html pagination working, but I'm trying to get the jQuery datatables plugin to have pagination.

Comment: Well this is the thing -- the `JQuery` datatables are populated from Rails. This means if you're using `will_paginate` on your SQL queries, you'll be only passing that page's data to your datatables. In order to get the pagination working across it all, you'll have to use the pagination links with ajax, returning new table data ([as per this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax))

Comment: The author is using datatables with an ajax source in his example. Putting will paginate in the view will not work with the features of datatables with searching, sorting, etc.

Answer (score -2):

you are doing it the wrong way. First donot use `will_paginate` when you are using `datatables` on the `same page`. You are seeing no pagination because, will paginate is limiting the no of records to 10. So for datatables to recognize and paginate your table you have to print all records on the page and datatables will find that there more than 10 rows in the table and paginates the table accordingly.

Comment: The railscast I provided uses will_paginate with datatables. Also, I'm trying to have the code be server side, instead of client-side so I need to have some way for the rails code to paginate itself.

Comment: The author is using datatables with an ajax source in his example. Not using pagination is a great way to make an app not be able to scale with hundreds of records, esp with any views or data dependent on additional queries.